# How to fix "Unable to fetch some archives" problem with apt-get dist-upgrade?

Tags: kali-linux

I have a problem with this command:

[image: Screenshot of error]

This is an abridged text version of the error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://XXXXXXXXXX:80/videoplayer/libpython2.7-dev_2.7.11-4_amd64.deb? ... Writing more data than expected (1391305>1387096)
E: Failed to fetch http://XXXXXXXXXX:80/videoplayer/john_1.8.0.6-jumbo-1-0kali9_amd64.deb? ... Writing more data than expected (68306>63312)
E: Failed to fetch http://XXXXXXXXXX:80/videoplayer/python-sip_4.17+dfsg-2_amd63.deb? ... Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://XXXXXXXXXX:80/videoplayer/libtexlua52_2015.20160222.37495-1_amd64.deb? ... Writing more data than expected (76707>70474)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with ---fix-missing?
```

I need to fix this? This is the problem when I type: `apt-get dist upgrade`.

I want to install a full upgrade to install an Nvidia driver (the red line is my IP address).

Comment: Don't post images when text will do. copy and paste the text (commands and output) from your terminal instead. Use the `{}` icon in the stackexchange editor to format it as code.  Text is searchable, editable, re-usable and legible in any screen size. It also works for vision impaired users. Images are none of those things and, worse, (from your POV) actively discourages people from making any effort to read your and answer your question.  i know i'm not going to bother spending 10 minutes squinting at it to try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: To copy in gnu/linux from a terminal, simply highlight the text you want to copy, then use your center mouse scroll wheel to paste it. One of the things I love in linux. As cas notes, don't post images because text is easy to read, search, google, etc, and images aren't. In fact, your image is so hard to decipher I'm not going to try. I've done a LOT of dist-upgrades and I have to admit I've never seen the "writing more data then expected" error. Post the actual text and maybe someone will take the time to debug your upgrade issues. I suggest running inxi -r as well to see what repos you have.

Comment: Key causes of dist upgrade breaks: 1. you're running a derived distro, which you are, and they have screwed up the packaging and broken apt. 2. apt failed to update and is in an inconsistent state. 3: you have a broken package in apt. 4: a specific package from a usually third party repo is broken or in an inconsistent state. For distro specific issues ask for help on your distro's forums, not here.

Comment: I checked, and yes, writing more data than expected is a simple packaging error, which means, the size of the binary does not match what apt was told to expect. This almost certainly means a package was done badly by someone who is sloppy, aka, a derived distro and/or a third party packager. The reason I've never seen this issue is that such an error would never pass the debian lintian package test process, which means it's an amateur package. Or it could mean, in theory, a man in the middle replaced your binary and it doesn't match in size, which is why apt checks for such mismatches.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a stab at an answer, even though there isn't enough data to actually do so. Don't take screenshots of your failures when you can trivially copy and paste the real text from your terminal to here. (highlight desired text block in terminal, the text is now in your copy cache, to paste it, click on your scroll wheel in a mouse, not sure the equivalent on a laptop). All commands are run as root user.

1. run the command: **apt-get update**

check for errors. If the update works, then do:

2. **apt-get dist-upgrade**
3. note that for debugging, doing a full dist-upgrade is a real pain, so really what you want to do is narrow it down to only the packages that are breaking. Personally I would not try to run a dist-upgrade with your apt package pool broken and in a damaged state, I'd remove the packages that are broken, hash mismatches, etc, because they will always break the upgrade, and you can't proceed until they are gone.
4. So check out which packages broke. Take those and use this command:
5. **apt-get --simulate remove --purge [your broken packages]**

**--simulate** is useful to see what would be removed if you remove those.

If not much important is removed, then just run the command again, without the simulate

6. **apt-get remove --purge [your broken packages]**
7. see if that is allowed.

Then run:

8. **apt-get install -f**
9. see what happens.
10. If everything seems fine, and apt is not complaining, then run:
11. **apt-get dist-upgrade**

Or, alternately, don't use derived distros, and don't run stuff from poorly packaged third party sources.

Usually once you get the junk broken packages out of your apt system, the upgrade will work fine, unless you're running something like Mint, in which case all bets are off, since they break both ubuntu AND debian apt package pools.

But also be aware, there's a reason Debian doesn't support derived distros as a general rule when it comes to support, and it's specifically because they can't control the packaging those distros do or use, which means they can't fix it for you or debug it for you.

Note also, there was NO need to do a dist-upgrade to get the new packaged nvidia driver, zero, none. All you needed to do was to install the package:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install [nvidia driver package name]
```

If you don't know the package name, just do:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
```

and you'll see it listed among the nvidia packages you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

"Hash mismatch" and "Writing more data than expected" are messages you might see when using a proxy.

Proxies can be transparent, as well as manually & consciously configured by you on your system.

I'm currently experiencing the same errors today, and believe that proxy caching is causing the errors. So far I have found no solution to the issue, having tried adding a proxy to my /.bashrc & also creating an apt.conf file with the following contents:

```
Acquire::http::No-Cache=True;
Acquire::https::No-Cache=True;
Acquire::http::proxy "http://10.254.132.254:80";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://10.254.132.254:80";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://10.254.132.254:80";
```

I know this post isn't much help without a solution, but perhaps you could check to see if this IS a proxy issue, and go from there?

Check your /.bashrc file firstly, to see if a proxy is configured for your shell:

```
cat ~/.bashrc
```

The relevant entries would look similar to the following:

```
http_proxy=http://<proxy_server>:<proxy_port>
export http_proxy
```

Other places to check include

1.the apt.conf file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ or /etc/apt/ - if found, look for lines referencing a proxy server, they're fairly clear like in the bash example.
If NOT found, don't worry, the file is not created by default.

2.the system's Network Settings: I access using the tools in the top-right of my Kali screen; click the drop-down in the upper-right, then the one beside your network adaptor, and select "Network Settings".
If a proxy is configured system-wide, it will be listed here.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get --fix-missing dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Could you [edit] and expand upon your answer to explain *why* this command might help fix the OP's issue?

Comment: Also, the last line of the screen shot appears to show the OP using this command, even though the output doesn't appear to be shown.